# Jquery mobile auto-redirects on select - phonegap

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, cordova-3

I have a small phonegap app running JQM 1.4.0 with 2 pages.

The issue is very similar to http://jsbin.com/ivifos/4/

On select of an option in page 1, it automatically redirects to page 0 (or the home page).

I did read through https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4595 and a few other pages but could not figure out a solution.

This is my change page script

```
    $.mobile.changePage( "#something", {
        changeHash: true
    });
```

P.S. changePage is depricated. the new change() gives me the same results.

Comment: What do you need to do ? changing page once an item is selected ?

Comment: No. I do not want the behavior in the demo mentioned above in the example. Is there a workaround to this bug?

Comment: No. I do not want the behavior in the demo mentioned above. Is there a workaround to this bug?

Comment: Can you add more code ? your change event of the select can be a good start